# Unable to start rabbitmq-server on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

I try to install `rabbitmq-server` on ubuntu-server 12.04 but failed.

Then I add the apt source list following the guide in http://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html

But reinstall still have the same error as following:

```
$ sudo aptitude install rabbitmq-server
...
Setting up rabbitmq-server (2.8.7-1) ...
 * Starting message broker rabbitmq-server
 * FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up rabbitmq-server (2.8.7-1) ...
 * Starting message broker rabbitmq-server
 * FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
   ...fail!
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
```

And error log seems show nothing useful neither:

```
# startup_err shows this
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})

# startup_log shows this
{error_logger,{{2012,10,10},{22,31,54}},"Protocol: ~p: register error: ~p~n",["inet_tcp",{{badmatch,{error,epmd_close}},[{inet_tcp_dist,listen,1},{net_kernel,start_protos,4},{net_kernel,start_protos,3},{net_kernel,init_node,2},{net_kernel,init,1},{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,10,10},{22,31,54}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.20.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.9.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[#Port<0.90>,<0.17.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,false}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,610},{stack_size,24},{reductions,511}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2012,10,10},{22,31,54}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_kernel},{mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,[[rabbitmqprelaunch18417,shortnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,10,10},{22,31,54}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,shutdown},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2012,10,10},{22,31,54}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
```

I have googled for some time but got nothing useful.

One solution on the internet is to make sure hostname pingable, but my `/etc/hosts` already have this line on top:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost    myserver
```

Any suggestion on how to get up rabbitmq-server?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep [r]abbit`?

Answer (score 11):

I faced this issue while installing rabbitmq-server, while I was installing chef.
The work around for me and the solution to this problem is given as follows.

```
    $ sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

Then add

```
    $ 127.0.0.1 <hostname>
```

Here  is your hostname, if not sure about the hostname then run the following command:

```
    $ hostname
```

the Result is your hostname. Just add that to your /etc/hosts and then run:

```
    $ sudo service rabbitmq-server start
```

And it was started.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

First, check `erl -sname foo` on your shell. If you get the same error, it may be an issue with [ubuntu erlang package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/erlang/+bug/1374109).

So I just installed the [newest erlang package](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp) and this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your firewall/port maybe block so that it cannot start up!

By default, you should enable 5672 (rabbit mq port) and 4365 (empd port)

Then restart it again it should work.

Comment: Thank you, my ufw was blocking these ports. Your comment fixed issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a problem related to `/etc/host` file. This file is not configure properly.**

Just open the file:

```
$ sudo -s
$ vim /etc/hosts
```

Check lines that start with "127.0.0.1" in this file (usually it's located on the top of the file).

Then make it look like this:

```
127.0.0.1  your host name
```

Then save and quit. Now restart `rabbitmq-server` and confirm that it works.

Comment: The question already states that `/etc/hosts` was ruled out.

Comment: Actually works. Though poorly worded

Answer (score 0):

I also got a similar error.( I do not have the logs as I restarted the rabbitmq-server for devstack)
My /etc/hosts file was well configured.

When rabbitmq_server fails, it logs certain information in erl_crash.dump.
In the file, I could see that the port 5672( where the server is deployed) is not free.
The same was visible from netstat -vtanp|grep 5672
The port was being used by beam.smp.
I stopped the process and restarted the rabbitmq-server, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that my firewall was blocking all local connections.

I had set the iptables policy for incoming packets to DROP. However, I needed to add a specific rule to allow packets coming from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Just for be sure, take a look to your local network

```
ip add
```

If there's no "lo" network, the you should enable it:

```
ifconfig lo up
```

Then restart the server again and let's see if it works again now

```
systemctl start rabbitmq-server
```