# RabbitMQ start failure

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, rabbitmq

I am trying to start RabbitMQ Server. And any way I do this, I get this error:

```
Starting rabbitmq-server: FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}
rabbitmq-server.
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing rabbitmq-server (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
rabbitmq-server
sE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to fix broken packages with:

```
$ sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

And even manually by editing `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. Also I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/436853/unable-to-start-rabbitmq-server-on-ubuntu-12-04), and modified my `hosts` file. Even though I am still encountering the same problem:

```
sE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Have no idea what to do. Does anybody know?
Thank you.

Comment: "check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}", sometimes it has the answer

Comment: @pinepain log file is empty, and err contains nothing except for failed starts list.